# Loop through each Control in a group box

Tags: excel, vba

I have a list of objects in an excel sheet, each has a checkbox and 4 drop downs inside a group box representing that object.

I can use VBA to loop through each groupbox in the sheet, but how do I loop through each control in the group box?

```
Dim oGroupBox As GroupBox
Dim cntrl As Control
For Each oGroupBox In Worksheets("Grapher").GroupBoxes
    For Each cntrl In oGroupBox.Controls
        Debug.Print (cntrl.Name)
    Next cntrl
Next oGroupBox
```

Comment: Typo? The inner For loop should ends with `Next cntrl`.

Comment: Sorry typo when transferring code from excel to this post. I think the problem is unsolvable as a GroupBox does not actually contain a Controls field

Answer (score 0):

Below assumes you don't have the FormControl shapes Grouped. It will list all the FormControl's Name that the TopLeftCell lies inside the GroupBox range (from *TopLeftCell* to *BottomRightCell*).

You can add new Sub code to act differently for each type of form controls you used.

```
Option Explicit

Sub ListControlsInGroupBoxes()
    Dim oGroupBox As GroupBox
    For Each oGroupBox In ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.GroupBoxes
        ListObjectsInGroupBox oGroupBox
    Next oGroupBox
End Sub

Private Sub ListObjectsInGroupBox(GBox As GroupBox)
    Dim oBoxRange As Range, oShp As Shape
    Set oBoxRange = Range(GBox.TopLeftCell, GBox.BottomRightCell)
    Debug.Print String(50, "-")
    Debug.Print "Group Box """ & GBox.Name & """ has range " & oBoxRange.Address
    For Each oShp In GBox.Parent.Shapes
        ' Deal only with FormControls
        If oShp.Type = msoFormControl Then
            ' Display FormControl's name if inside the GroupBox range
            If Not Intersect(oShp.TopLeftCell, oBoxRange) Is Nothing Then
                ' Obmit itself
                If Not oShp Is GBox Then
                    Debug.Print """" & oShp.Name & """"
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next oShp
    Set oBoxRange = Nothing
End Sub
```